# printing the total in text field order form

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating an order form where the quantity is where the user will input in the text field, whereas the price is already stored in the database.

I want the quantity of product to be times with the price of the product and diplay the result in the total field.

And then count all the total and display in the ORDER TOTAL field. But I'm stuck in the middle of it, and I'm not sure how to do it.

I was hoping someone could guide me in this. Here's my code:

```
<?php
//setting connection to the database
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "SCINFO");
//checking the connection
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Connection Failed!";
}
?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Order -- SHOPPERS||COLLECTION</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2 align="left">Purchase/Order Items</h2>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); >">
<table cellpadding="15">
<tr bgcolor="#996699">
    <td>Product ID</td>
    <td>Product Name</td>
    <td>Quantity</td>
    <td>Price (RM)</td>
    <td>Total</td>
</tr>
<?php
    //prints the data in table
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM PRODUCT");
    // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result)) {
        // echo out the contents of each row
        echo "<tr>";
        echo '<td>' . $row['PRD_ID'] . '</td>';     //prints out the product ID
        echo '<td>' . $row['PRD_NAME'] . '</td>';   //prints out the product name 
        echo '<td><input type="text" name="qty"> X</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['PRD_PRICE'].'</td>';
        echo '<td><input type="text" name="total" value="" disabled="disabled"></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
?>
<tr>
    <td colspan="5"><hr></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="4" align="right">ORDER TOTAL:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="ototal" value="RM " disabled="disabled"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="4" align="right"><input type="submit" name="submit"  value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
    if($_POST["submit"]){
        $qty = $_POST['qty'];
        $price = $_POST['prc'];
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
           $sum = $qty * $price;
        }
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you've nothing for `$_POST['prc']` if you want to do math and multiply, use `*`  To add `+` . substract `-` and divide `/` which is basically what you're doing now.

Comment: @Fred-ii- well I wanted the prc to be equal to the product price in the database.. and I'm not sure how to do that ---edited--- If i set $price = $row["PRD_PRICE"] will it work?

Comment: Do you want to refresh the page each time you put in a quantity and show the price as it changes? If so, you're going to need tome JavaScript.

Comment: @JayBlanchard yes but I'm not very familiar with javascript

Comment: "Yes" meaning you want to refresh the page?

Comment: @JayBlanchard yes i do want to refresh the page

Comment: If you want to actually refresh the page no JavaScript is needed. Insert a quantity, click a button, do the math during the reload.

Answer (score 0):

if you are saying that the price is already in database then why are you using `$_POST['prc']` ? Because till best of my knowledge the `$_POST[]` is used when you want to get value from form. let suppose

```
 <html>
    <body>
      <form method="post" >
          <input type="text" name="userName" value="" />
          <input type="submit" value="Click me"
      </form>          


<?php
       if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
// POST is used to collect value of input field
         $name = $_POST['userName'];
         if (empty($name)) 
          {
           echo "Name is empty";
          } else {
           echo $name;
          }    
         ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```